# UIkit crashes also not able to reproduce

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

```
Thread 0: Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3a6285b0 objc_msgSend + 15
1  UIKit                          0x348285f5 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 92
2  UIKit                          0x348284c1 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 324
3  UIKit                          0x347f94e9 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 180
4  UIKit                          0x347b8803 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 258
5  QuartzCore                     0x34562d8b -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 214
6  QuartzCore                     0x34562929 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 460
7  QuartzCore                     0x3456385d CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
8  QuartzCore                     0x34563243 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 238
9  QuartzCore                     0x34563051 CA::Transaction::commit() + 316
10 UIKit                          0x34988369 -[UIApplication _sendOrderedOutContextsAndInvalidate:] + 112
11 UIKit                          0x3483863f orderOutContextObserverCallout + 34
12 CoreFoundation                 0x329826cd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
13 CoreFoundation                 0x329809c1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 276
14 CoreFoundation                 0x32980c91 __CFRunLoopRun + 608
15 CoreFoundation                 0x328f3ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
16 CoreFoundation                 0x328f3d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
17 GraphicsServices               0x364a62eb GSEventRunModal + 74
18 UIKit                          0x34809301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
19 test                           0x000f610f main (main.m:16)
```

I get this error in my crashlytics but not able to reproduce this error. Can any one help me to solve this how can i get rid of this crash.

Comment: it sounds like you are performing UIKit operation on back ground/non-main thread,are you able to reproduce this bug, can you show us the culprit code.get that code by putting break point.

Comment: Have you checked your log msg by enabling zombie?

Comment: I have check my all code also test it with NSZombie but not able to reproduce that. It comes suddenly on users device. I am not able to reproduce also not getting any idea how could i remove that?